# Tensor method under high noise

Tags: machine-learning, references, tensor

Tensor methods give good results under low approximation error. (e.g. at 7min http://videolectures.net/iclr2016_anandkumar_nonconvex_learning/). I am wondering how do they do when the noise in the signal is high. Is it related to 'low approximation error'? Any introductory readings are much appreciated. Also, please feel free to point to other paradigms of learning which have been successful for high noise cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is an out-growth of the spectral method literature, which goes back to the seminal paper by Hsu et al.[1]. There are many recent advances in the area, notably [2] and [3] for their relevance to machine learning.

[1] Hsu, D., Kakade, S. M., & Zhang, T. (2012). A spectral algorithm for learning hidden Markov models. Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 78(5), 1460-1480.

[2] Sedghi, H., & Anandkumar, A. (2016). Training Input-Output Recurrent Neural Networks through Spectral Methods. arXiv preprint arXiv:1603.00954.

[3] Azizzadenesheli, K., Lazaric, A., & Anandkumar, A. (2016). Reinforcement Learning of POMDPs using Spectral Methods. arXiv preprint arXiv:1602.07764.